# Reset PeakWorkingSetSize

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory

I am currently looking for a way to measure the peak memory consumption of several C functions. The functions are part of legacy C libraries with no source code available.
My goal is to measure which of them has the lowest memory consumption. Currently, I am using the PeakWorkingSetSize field returned by the GetProcessMemoryInfo call of the WinAPI (c.f.https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/psapi/collecting-memory-usage-information-for-a-process). Unfortunately, there seems to be no simple way to reset this counter. If there was one, I would simply do the following:

```
int peak = getPeak();
functionCall1();
int d1 = getPeak() - peak;
resetPeak();
peak = getPeak();
functionCall2();
int d2 = getPeak() - peak;
resetPeak();
peak = getPeak();
functionCall3();
int d3 = getPeak() - peak;
```

Does anyone know a way to reset this counter or knows another approach to solve my problem. I am not forced to Windows, however it would be great if there is a solution for windows. In addition, the result does not have to be rough estimate is totally fine.

Comment: To reset the counter, tear down the process and start over.

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to reset it. But you could use [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) for each function call. Take 3 functions as an example:

getpeak.exe:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

int getPeak()
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc)))
    {
        return pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize;
    }
    return 0;
}
void functionCall1()
{
    //To Do
}
void functionCall2()
{
    //To Do
}
void functionCall3()
{
    //To Do
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("format: \"getpeak.exe index\"\n");
    }
    int peak = getPeak();
    switch (atoi(argv[1]))
    {
    case 1:
        functionCall1();
        break;
    case 2:
        functionCall2();
        break;
    case 3:
        functionCall3();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invaild function index\n");
        break;
    }
    int d = getPeak() - peak;
    return d;
}
```

Call `CreateProcess` for each function call like:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    DWORD d1 = 0, d2 = 0, d3 = 0;
    TCHAR cmd[3][20] = {"getpeak.exe 1","getpeak.exe 2","getpeak.exe 3"};
    STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd[0], NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &d3);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd[1], NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &d2);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd[2], NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &d3);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(Remove part of error checking)